# active Navbar BOOTSTRAP v4

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to activate link when filtering by category in navbar. But with this code both of this category activates. I think my if statements in HTML working wrong.

search_results.html

```
<li class="nav-item {% if search_category == BP%}active{% endif%}">
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core:get_category' %}?search_item=BP">Building Products</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item {% if search_category == BP%}active{% endif%}">
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core:get_category' %}?search_item=OT">Other Products</a>
</li>
```

method get_category in views.py

```
def get_category(request):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    search_category = request.GET.get('search_item','')
    if search_category:
       queryset = queryset.filter(category__icontains = search_category)
    context ={
        'queryset': queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

When searching by Building prod

```
Print(search_category)
BP

Print(search_item)
<QueryDict: {'search_item': ['BP']}>
```

When searching by Other prod

```
Print(search_category)
OT

Print(search_item)
<QueryDict: {'search_item': ['OT']}>
```

Comment: I think `BP` should be compared as string `{% if search_category == 'BP'%}active{% endif%}`

Comment: if i use BP as string nothing will happen. The navbar didn't react.